# Can I combine and re-split 2 coaxial cables for 2 signals in my home?

Tags: wiring, cables

I have an existing coaxial cable running to my modem through the wall outside from my ISP. I bought an external digital antenna that I'd also like to run outside, but I don't want to drill a second hole and socket through the wall.

Can I use two splitters and temporarily run both signals through the same cable in the wall? So it would look like:

```
(outside) | (wall) | (inside)
ISP                     modem
---------           ---------
         > ------- <
---------           ---------
antenna                    TV
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1177379/can-single-incoming-coaxial-cable-carry-signals-for-2-separate-services-cable-m - duplicate, but from another site. In short - no.

Comment: The short answer is no. The long answer is maybe, but you'd need more than a splitter.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple:

No.

Not with splitters.

Not with directional couplers.

Not in any practical way.

Signal bandwidths overlap.

Answer (score 0):

If the cable has the VHF/UHF cable channels blocked and only passes the modem RF channel AND your OTA sign has 7dB excess SNR AND your cable modem has 7dB excess SNR AND you are not too close to the TV tower in a high Appt level to cause TV interference on modem RF channel...

THEN if all conditions are met, you can combine both cables then split them on one inter-wall coax without loss of BER or modem rate.

But it is not hard to drill an extra hole if you can borrow a concrete drill bit with a hammer drill.